# email notification if file is not uploaded to S3 Bucket

Tags: python-3.x, file, boto3, boto

I am uploading file to S3 bucket thru Boto3.

Need help on Python code for email notification if a file is not uploaded to S3 bucket

Could any one share the python code please

Thanks
xxxx